# How to select rows that not consist of only NaN values and 0s

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
cols = ['Country', 'Year', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Plump']

data = [['US', 2008, 17, 29, 19],
        ['US', 2009, 11, 12, 16],
        ['US', 2010, 14, 16, 38],
        ['Spain', 2008, 11, None, 33],
        ['Spain', 2009, 12, 19, 17],
        ['France', 2008, 17, 19, 21],
        ['France', 2009, 19, 22, 13],
        ['France', 2010, 12, 11, 0],
        ['France', 2010, 0, 0, 0],
        ['Italy', 2009, None, None, None],
        ['Italy', 2010, 15, 16, 17],
        ['Italy', 2010, 0, None, None],
        ['Italy', 2011, 42, None, None]]
```

I want to select rows which in which orange apple and plumps are not consist of only "None"s, only 0s or mix of them. So the Resulting output should be:

```
   Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump  
0       US  2008    17.0   29.0   19.0  
1       US  2009    11.0   12.0   16.0  
2       US  2010    14.0   16.0   38.0  
3    Spain  2008    11.0    NaN   33.0  
4    Spain  2009    12.0   19.0   17.0  
5   France  2008    17.0   19.0   21.0 
6   France  2009    19.0   22.0   13.0  
7   France  2010    12.0   11.0    0.0  
10   Italy  2010    15.0   16.0   17.0  
12   Italy  2011    42.0    NaN    NaN
```

Second I want to drop the countries for which I don't have observations for all three years. So resulting output should only consist Us and France. How I could get them ?
I have tried something like:

```
df = df[(df['Orange'].notnull())| \
            (df['Apple'].notnull()) | (df['Plump'].notnull()) | (df['Orange'] != 0 )| (df['Apple']!= 0) | (df['Plump']!= 0)]
```

Also I tried:

```
df = df[((df['Orange'].notnull())| \
                (df['Apple'].notnull()) | (df['Plump'].notnull())) & ((df['Orange'] != 0 )| (df['Apple']!= 0) | (df['Plump']!= 0))]
```

Comment: I will update what I have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [307]: df[~df[['Orange','Apple','Plump']].fillna(0).eq(0).all(1)]
Out[307]:
   Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump
0       US  2008    17.0   29.0   19.0
1       US  2009    11.0   12.0   16.0
2       US  2010    14.0   16.0   38.0
3    Spain  2008    11.0    NaN   33.0
4    Spain  2009    12.0   19.0   17.0
5   France  2008    17.0   19.0   21.0
6   France  2009    19.0   22.0   13.0
7   France  2010    12.0   11.0    0.0
10   Italy  2010    15.0   16.0   17.0
12   Italy  2011    42.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But also I want to get rid of 8th row which consist of all 0s

Comment: @ MaxU Perfect answer as usual

Comment: Okay, that was clever.  I was thinking to do null-or-==-0, but fillna(0).eq(0) is pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

None values are going to be read as NaN, so you can replace 0s and convert them as NaN as well. After that you can do what MaxU suggested you. That would be something like:

```
In: df = df.replace(0,np.nan)
    df = df[df[['Orange','Apple','Plump']].notnull().any(1)]
Out:
   Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump

0       US  2008      17     29     19
1       US  2009      11     12     16
2       US  2010      14     16     38
3    Spain  2008      11    NaN     33
4    Spain  2009      12     19     17
5   France  2008      17     19     21
6   France  2009      19     22     13
7   France  2010      12     11    NaN
10   Italy  2010      15     16     17
12   Italy  2011      42    NaN    NaN
```

For your second question I understand in this case you want to get rid of countries for which you don't have observations for 2008,2009,2010.
For that you could do something like:

```
countries = []
for group,values in enumerate(df.groupby('Country')):
    lista = values[1].Year.unique() == [2008,2009,2010]
    if (np.all(lista)):
        countries.append(values[0])
df = df[df.Country.isin(countries)]
```

Which will yield something like:

```
  Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump
0      US  2008      17     29     19
1      US  2009      11     12     16
2      US  2010      14     16     38
5  France  2008      17     19     21
6  France  2009      19     22     13
7  France  2010      12     11    NaN
8  France  2010     NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Finally you can apply both solutions at the same time doing:

```
df[df[['Orange','Apple','Plump']].notnull().any(1) & df.Country.isin(countries)])
```

Getting:

```
  Country  Year  Orange  Apple  Plump
0      US  2008      17     29     19
1      US  2009      11     12     16
2      US  2010      14     16     38
5  France  2008      17     19     21
6  France  2009      19     22     13   
7  France  2010      12     11    NaN
```